# Avoiding plain text passwords in parameters for SAP OCI punchout

Tags: security, sap-srm

When SAP's OCI punchout is used, connecting to a supplier system appears to start with hitting a URL that contains the user and password for the supplier system as a plain text parameter. Is there a way to make this more secure? Even though https is used, the user and password would be visible in logs and such.

Seems like could encrypt the password (and username). That's not great since someone could reuse that, but it would definitely be better leaving the passwords in plain text. Is this kind of thing done? Does SAP support it ok? Any other approaches people use for addressing this?

Comment: I could hardly believe it, but it seems that even now in 2017 the common practice for SAP OCI punchout is to pass user & password as query parameters ...

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to send the USERNAME and PASSWORD parameters as part of the POST body, so they won't be in the URL. Using HTTPS will encrypt the password while in transport.

However, this is still not secure because the POST request is sent from the end user's browser - so the credentials are exposed to the end user. More info here: https://punchoutcommerce.com/guides/punchout/oci-roundtrip/